# How to remove leading zero with Perl's 'sprintf'

Tags: perl

How do I print half as .500 using `sprintf` instead of 0.500?

Both statements below print 0.500.

```
my $half = 1/2;

print sprintf("%0.3f\n", $half);
print sprintf("%.3f\n", $half);
```

Comment: Why do you want to omit the leading zero; it is much better/safer/more readable to include it.

Comment: I agree. but just to match with some old legacy code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't possible to do using `sprintf` alone. You can use the code you have and then remove the leading zero using whatever method you like (regex is easy).

```
my $half = 1 / 2;
my $format = sprintf("%.3f", $half);
$format =~ s/^0//;
print "$format\n";
```

Comment: In 5.14+: `say sprintf("%.3f", $half) =~ s/^0//r;`